# How to rewrite as a loop when I have identical frames for different years and the year is in the name?

Tags: r, loops, lapply

I am new, so this question is a bit basic, but it might help others get a good start as well...

How to rewrite the below as a loop and have it include the years in the new names, as below...

```
DFNUM2011 = DF2011[,!(names(DF2011) %in% mydummies)]
DFNUM2012 = DF2012[,!(names(DF2012) %in% mydummies)]
DFNUM2013 = DF2013[,!(names(DF2013) %in% mydummies)]
```

I tried

```
 df.list<-list("2011","2012","2013")
> for (i in df.list){
+   DFNUM[[i]] = DF[[i]][,!(names(DF2011) %in% mydummies)]
+ }
Error in DF : object 'DF' not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can work:

```
#List
List <- list(DFNUM2011,DFNUM2012,DFNUM2013)
#Loop
for (i in seq_along(List))
{
   List[[i]] = List[[i]][,!(names(List[[i]]) %in% mydummies)]
}
```

A working example can be:

```
#Example
List <- list(iris,mtcars)
mydummies <- c('Species','mpg')
#Loop
for (i in seq_along(List))
{
  List[[i]] = List[[i]][,!(names(List[[i]]) %in% mydummies)]
}
```

And a more compact way without loops:

```
#Code
List <- lapply(List, function(x) {x<-x[,!names(x) %in% mydummies]})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
library(purrr)

n <- 2011:2013
result <- map(mget(paste0('DF', n)), ~keep(.x, !(names(.x) %in% mydummies)))
```

If you want to create new dataframes with different names in your global environment.

```
names(result) <- paste0('DFNUM', n)
list2env(result, .GlobalEnv)
```

This should create `DFNUM2011`, `DFNUM2012` and `DFNUM2013` dataframes.